# locationListener doesn't work after 30 seconds on foreground service

Tags: android, android-location, foreground-service, android-10.0

I have created a service which finds and then stores the user's coordinates in an SQLite database.

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {

DatabaseHelper myDb;

private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

private String latitude, longitude;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Service")
            .setContentText("Coordinates Location Running")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.d("myTag", "Hello");

            latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            insertCoordinates(latitude, longitude);

            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            i.putExtra("longitude",longitude);

            sendBroadcast(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    if(locationManager != null)
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

}

private void insertCoordinates(String latitude, String longitude) {

    boolean inserted = myDb.insertData(latitude, longitude); //Insert coordinates

    //Check if insertion is completed
    if(inserted)
        Toast.makeText(GPS_Service.this, "Coordinates Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(GPS_Service.this, "Coordinates Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

I can either start or stop the service from the MainActivity like this

```
private void enable_buttons() {

    buttonStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS_Service.class);

            //Checks if the SDK version is higher than 26 to act accordingly
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(MainActivity.this, serviceIntent);

        }
    });

    buttonStopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GPS_Service.class);
            stopService(serviceIntent);

        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that when I start this service, if I either completely close the app or leave it in the background, the locationListener will work for 30 seconds and then it will stop. If I reopen the app, the service continues to work from where it stopped. Also I checked in the developer options if the service is running, and it indeed is even though the locationListener doesn't output the expected results. Any ideas?

Comment: Your device is probably going to sleep, and the clock is stopping. See [WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock).

Comment: I acquired the wake lock when I start the service and release it when I destroy it but it didn't work

Comment: Please edit your post to include your wakelock code. If you want to be certain it is working, try doing some work about once a second, such as writing a line to logcat. You can schedule a Runnable every 1000ms, for instance. If it becomes irregular, or stops, after 30 seconds, then you know you have a sleep problem. If it doesn't, then you know you don't.

Comment: I tried to log two messages, one inside the onLocationChanged function, and one inside the onStartCommand function but outside of onLocationChanged. After 30 seconds, the message which was inside the onLocationChanged stopped printing, but the other message kept printing indefinitely. This worked without including a wakelock. I really don't understand what's the problem

Comment: "inside the onStartCommand function..." Help me understand something, here. What is causing your `onStartCommand` function to repeatedly execute?

Comment: I created a CountDownTimer that runs every 10 seconds and logs a message.

Comment: OK, got it. Just to be perfectly clear, you created a `CountDownTimer` in `onStartCommand()` to do one logger, and you were referring to your `Log.d("myTag", "Hello")` as the logger that _stops_ executing after 30 seconds (not a CountDownTimer).

Comment: This is rather strange. Have you confirmed `Service.onDestroy()` is not executing?

Comment: And, I'd like to establish just how close to 30 seconds the fault manifests. If you reduce the reporting `minTime` to, say, 500ms, how long does it take to stop working?

Comment: Yes that's correct. How can I check if Sevice.OnDestroy() is not executing? I tried to comment the code inside it but got the same result. I also tried 500ms and it is exactly 30s. I also noticed something weird, the message I log inside the onStartCommand() keeps logging even after I stop the service with my button. I can confirm the service is stopped as it disappears from the developer options.

Comment: 1. Just use a logger or a breakpoint. 2. This is normal. When you create a `CountDownTimer` inside `onStartCommand()` or any other function, it doesn't actually "run inside" that function. It executes by continually re-posting itself to the main thread `Handler`. And it doesn't know (or care) if your `Service` has stopped, even though the `Service` may have "created" it, in some sense, it does not "belong" to the service; it belongs to the JVM/main thread.

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: I used a logger and it didn't log anything. Only after I stopped the service with my button it did. I use an Emulator Pixel 3.

Comment: An emulator? If you go to Emulator Settings->Location, verify "GPS data playback" is empty. After 30 seconds passes, try manually changing the lat/long, and hit "Send". Do you get another fix?

Comment: GPS data playback is empty. Tried to change the lat/long values and hitting send after 30 seconds but nothing changed

Comment: And the foreground notification is present during this entire time?

Comment: Correct, it only goes away after I stop the service with my button.

Comment: I'm running pretty low on ideas. This doesn't really add up. Case could be, it'll work on a real device if you try it, b/c emulators have funny GPS behaviors. I'd double-check the logcat (unfiltered) for any strange messages. If you tell me the exact AVD image you're using, I'll try and reproduce the problem in a couple days.

Comment: Where can I see the exact AVD image that I'm using?

Comment: Good question. I think if you tell me the Android version #, and ABI (x86?) you chose when creating the emulator, that will be close enough.

Comment: Pixel 3  API 29 Android 10 x84 is what I use, thank you for your time either way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Add `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` to your `Service's` manifest entry.

**EXPLANATION**

This new behavior, for Android 10, is exactly as you've described: Even though you may be using a foreground service, 30 seconds after your app leaves the screen -- location updates cease.

You might've noticed that Android 10 devices present two new choices to the user when granting location permissions (for legacy (API < 29) apps, or apps that declare the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission):

- "Allow all the time"
- "Allow only while using this app"

"Allow only while using this app" effectively means, "Allow while the *app is visible onscreen*". That's because the user now has the option of selectively removing location access -- even to a foreground service -- based on that criteria. Users can change this setting *at any time*, even if your app is running.

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#continue-user-initiated-action) explain that the solution, `android:foregroundServiceType="location"`, was intended for your precise use case: "Google Maps"-like apps, which have a foreground service, but are expected to continue processing location data if the user switches to another app. The technique is called "continuing a user-initiated action", and it allows you to get location updates even after your app is placed in the "background".

(The docs seem to be expanding the definition of the term "background", here. In the past, if you had a foreground service, your app was considered "in the foreground" -- at least for the purposes of task priority, Doze, and so forth. Now it appears that an app is considered "in the background", with respect to location access, if it hasn't been onscreen in the last 30 seconds.)

I am not sure what UI changes (like in the Google Play store) take place when you set a particular `foregroundServiceType`. Regardless, it seems to me that users are unlikely to object.

**OTHER SOLUTIONS FOR ANDROID 10 DEVICES**

Alternatively, you could've declared a `targetSdkVersion` of 28 or less, which will let your app function in a location "compatibility mode".

You also have the option of gaining the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission, but the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#request-background-location) caution against this:

> If your app doesn't require location access while running in the background, it's highly recommended that you not request `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`...

This approach isn't required, for your use case, because your `Activity` is used to start your `Service`; you can be guaranteed that your app has been onscreen at least once before the `Service` starts getting background location updates. (At least, I *assume* that that is how the OS determines the start of a "user-initiated action". Presumably, the `foregroundServiceType` approach won't work if you're starting the `Service` from a `JobScheduler`, or a `BroadcastReceiver`, or something.)

**PS:** Hang on to that `WakeLock` code. You're going to need to keep the device awake, if you want to keep getting updates at a steady 10-second pace.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you! I have another question though since you mentioned that this won't work if I'm starting the `Service` from a `JobScheduler`. In the future I'm planning to activate this `Service` for, let's say, every 5 minutes with a `JobScheduler`, in this case, what should I do for it to work? Should I add `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` to the manifest file?

Comment: Also, is it correct if I initialize my `WakeLock` on the `onCreate()`, `acquire()` it on the `onStartCommand()` and `release()` it on the `onDestroy()` ?

Comment: @IraklisEleftheriadis You're welcome. Yes, for a `JobScheduler`, `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` should get you what you need. Now, your `WakeLock` probably just needs to cover the area between `requestLocationUpdates()` and `removeUpdates()`. Whether you start this in `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` is really just a matter of taste, since for your implementation, `onCreate()` will always be followed immediately by an `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Re the WakeLock, is it really needed? The 'Strava' tracking app records locations at 1 second intervals, I think, but I'm not required to alow wakelock permission. (not on Oreo anyway).

Comment: @quilkin I believe it is needed, otherwise you will find that processing ceases when the device is unplugged from the charger, etc. Not familiar with the "Strava" app, but according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WAKE_LOCK), `WAKE_LOCK` is a "normal" permission that doesn't require user consent.

Comment: @greeble31 could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284432/how-to-create-location-foreground-service-without-google-play-service

Answer (score -1):

I dont really see any problem in the code, but I am a bit sceptical about `START_NOT_STICKY`. Try `START_STICKY` instead.

START_STICKY

> If this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the
>   started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system
>   will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state,
>   it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after
>   creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start
>   commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null
>   intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

START_NOT_STICKY

> If this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new
>   start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the
>   started state and don't recreate until a future explicit call to
>   Context.startService(Intent). The service will not receive a
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent because it
>   will not be re-started if there are no pending Intents to deliver.

So as you are returning `START_NOT_STICKY`, if the process is killed, onStartCommand() will not be called again, which is where you initialize both the listener and the locationManager.

Comment: Actually, the `STICKY/NOT_STICKY` return codes have to do more with the OS behavior after it has "involuntarily terminated" your app. This doesn't really apply to this case, b/c, since the OP is using a foreground service, it's probably not going to be terminated. It's going to run "high-priority".