# Background service stops after 20 sec after destroy app in Android 10 java

Tags: java, android, service, background-process, android-10.0

i have an app that detects the location in the background. In the devices with android 9 (api 28) or lower it works, but in android 10 it stops after 20 sec

there is some code

how i call the service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
startService(intent);
```

main activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleService.str_receiver));
    }
```

google service

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5, notify_interval);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    }
```

Comment: "In the devices with android 9 (api 28) or lower it works" -- it should be stopping in one minute on Android 8.0 and higher: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Comment: Assuming this is _not_ "idle" (as mentioned by CommonsWare), then it could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746210/locationlistener-doesnt-work-after-30-seconds-on-foreground-service/58782096#58782096). 20 seconds is awfully close to 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you WANT it to stop, or do you want it to keep running?  And also, it depends on whether it's just, they've closed the app, or whether they've gone into the settings and clicked "Force stop" - there's not a lot you can do if the user really wants your app stopped.

Comment: in android 9.0 and 8.0 it works i tried it on the physical devices.

Comment: i know about "force stop" but i need that the app keep running after close

Answer (score 1):

As CommonsWare noted, running a background service like this will result in the system killing it after the user leaves your app on newer versions of Android.

Depending on the exact characteristics of how you're trying to do this, you should either use WorkManager (if this is deferrable and not needed more than every 15 minutes or so) or a foreground service with a notification (if you need to query constantly).  See [this guide from the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work) for more information on your options here.